# Best practice for complex TSQL view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a complex View for a report below:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ID, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_LBR_HRS, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.CUSTNAME, 
                  dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.JOBNBR, CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), 
                  dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY) END AS COMPQTY, CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), 
                  dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END AS ORDQTY, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.PLAN_CD, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.PLANQTY, 
                  dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ITEMNBR, dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF.ITEM_NBR, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WODUEDT, tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.WRK_CENTER_DESC, 
                  tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.LABOR_CAPACITY, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_SETUP_HRS, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.STD_LBR_HOURS, 
                  dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS, 
                  dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPERATION_NBR, tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.WAREHOUSE, 
                  CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20005' THEN 1 WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20010' THEN 2 WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR
                   = '20020' THEN 3 WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20030' THEN 4 WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20040' THEN 5 WHEN
                   dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20050' THEN 6 WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20110' THEN 7 ELSE dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR
                   END AS WCOrder, DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(dw, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE), dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE) AS WeekEnd, 
                  DATEPART(wk, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE) AS WkNum, 
                  CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY <> 0 THEN ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_LBR_HRS / dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) 
                  * (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY - dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY)) 
                  * 2 ELSE ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_LBR_HRS / dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) * (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY)) * 2 END AS RmnLabor, 
                  CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY <> 0 THEN ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_SETUP_HRS / tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) 
                  * (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY - dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY)) 
                  / 100 ELSE ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_SETUP_HRS / dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) * (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY)) 
                  / 100 END AS RmnSetup
FROM         dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF ON dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF.CPN =  dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.CPN_NO INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF AS tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF ON dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WC_NBR = tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.ID INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF ON dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ID = dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.ID
WHERE     (dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE <= DATEADD(m, 2, GETDATE())) AND (dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS <> 'C' OR
                  dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS IS NULL OR
                  dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS = '') AND (tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.WAREHOUSE = '02') AND (dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR IN ('20005', '20010', 
                  '20020', '20030', '20040', '20060', '20110')) AND (NOT (dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF.ITEM_NBR LIKE 'A%')) AND (CASE WHEN tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL 
                  THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END <> 0) AND (CASE WHEN tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL 
                  THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END <> 0)
ORDER BY dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WODUEDT DESC
```

I would like to make this run more efficient. 
I am also curious if what I am doing is the proper way to write the View and if I should refactor it...??

Ryan

Comment: Have you looked at adding any indexes?

Comment: Adding aliases for your tables would make your query a lot more readable / manageable...

Comment: Especially *short* (but meaningful) aliases.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Those are all good points. The query is not terrible as far as speed but I want to make sure it is designed the best.

Comment: What is the date type of tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY and does it allow null?  A more readable query is easier to optimize and a question that is easier to read will get more and better answers.

Comment: It also looks like the `AND (CASE WHEN tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END <> 0) ` is duplicated in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Blam The column ORDQTY is varchar but the alias column does not seem to work in calculations after converting to decimal. The database is a very old ERP system, and the data types and tables are kind of poorly designed.

Comment: Yeah jpw, I am not sure why that was done.

Comment: The last two CASEs seem to be trying to prevent division by zero exceptions but they've got the condition backwards: `CASE WHEN a <> 0 THEN ... / (a - b) ELSE ... / a END`. It should instead be `CASE WHEN a = 0 THEN ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, best practice on `views` is not to include an `ORDER BY`.  So get rid of the `TOP (100) PERCENT` and the `ORDER BY dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WODUEDT DESC` statements.  Next format your query so it's easily readable.  I've done this below, but if you have a different format you prefer use that.  It's all about making it readable for YOU and YOUR teammates/eventual replacement.

Having formatted it I can tell you that you should check on the following indexes.

- tbl_ITEMMAST_NF(CPN, ITEM_NBR)
- tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF(CPN_NO, WC_NBR, ID, ORDQTY)
- tbl_WIPOPER_NF(ID, SCHED_COMP_DATE, OPER_STATUS)

These are a starting place based on the columns you are using in the `JOIN`s and the `WHERE` clause.  They may not be optimal but will probably be better than nothing.  You might also check the execution plan and see if the optimizer suggests something.  If it does review your existing indexes and see if it fits in with them, and if it does, then add it.  If not it may be possible to modify one of your existing indexes to cover what it is asking for.

For example let's say you created the indexes above but the optimizer wants the following index.

```
tbl_WIPOPER_NF(ID, SCHED_COMP_DATE, OPER_STATUS) INCLUDE WORK_CENTER_NBR
```

Don't just add a new index.  Modify the old one to include the `INCLUDE`ed columns.  Or the optimizer may want you to change the order of the columns in the index.  If this is the only place you are using that index (you added it because I suggested it) then modify it.  Don't add a new one.  Same goes for my suggestions above when compared to the indexes you already have.

As far as the query itself.  It looks fine.  There are some other ways to handle things, for example using `ISNULL` instead of your `CASE` statements in the `WHERE` clause.  But the way you have it should work just fine.

```
SELECT --TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ID, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_LBR_HRS, 
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.CUSTNAME, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.JOBNBR, 
    CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY) END AS COMPQTY, 
    CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END AS ORDQTY, 
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.PLAN_CD, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.PLANQTY, 
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ITEMNBR, dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF.ITEM_NBR, 
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WODUEDT, tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.WRK_CENTER_DESC, 
    tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.LABOR_CAPACITY, dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_SETUP_HRS, 
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.STD_LBR_HOURS, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE, 
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS, 
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPERATION_NBR, tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.WAREHOUSE, 
    CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20005' THEN 1 
        WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20010' THEN 2 
        WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20020' THEN 3 
        WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20030' THEN 4 
        WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20040' THEN 5 
        WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20050' THEN 6 
        WHEN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20110' THEN 7 
        ELSE dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR END AS WCOrder, 
    DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(dw, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE), 
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE) AS WeekEnd, DATEPART(wk, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE) AS WkNum, 
    CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY <> 0 
        THEN ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_LBR_HRS / dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) *
            (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY - dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY)) * 2 
        ELSE ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_LBR_HRS / dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) * 
            (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY)) * 2 END AS RmnLabor, 
    CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY <> 0 
        THEN ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_SETUP_HRS / tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) * 
            (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY - dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY)) / 100 
        ELSE ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_SETUP_HRS / dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) * 
            (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY)) / 100 END AS RmnSetup
FROM dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF 
    ON dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF.CPN =  dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.CPN_NO 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF AS tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF 
    ON dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WC_NBR = tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF 
    ON dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ID = dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.ID
WHERE (dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE <= DATEADD(m, 2, GETDATE())) 
  AND (dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS <> 'C' OR
        dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS IS NULL OR
        dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS = '') 
  AND (tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.WAREHOUSE = '02') 
  AND (dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR IN ('20005', '20010', '20020', '20030', 
                                                '20040', '20060', '20110')) 
  AND (NOT (dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF.ITEM_NBR LIKE 'A%')) 
  AND (CASE WHEN tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END <> 0) 
  AND (CASE WHEN tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END <> 0)
--ORDER BY dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WODUEDT DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Kenneth Fisher, great answer. I appreciate your time. I need to add indexes across many previously programmed Views

Comment: I ended up just putting all the calcs in calulated fields in ssrs

Answer (score 2):

This just makes no sense to me

```
where      
(CASE 
      WHEN tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL THEN 0 
      ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END 
       <> 0)
```

If it is null then it returns false.
But any comparison to null returns false.

It has to be a numeric type for convert to decimal to succeed.
With any numeric type <> 0 is the same.

Pretty sure that can be reduced to

```
where tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY <> 0
```

With your syntax you kill the use of an index on that column

Also <> 'c' or = '' is redundant

Saw comment that tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY is varchar.
That is just messed up.
That convert will fail if any varchar value is not decimal.
I just assumed it had to be some type of numeric.

Comment: Blam, I inherited this database and reports from a previous employee, and having to reprogram alot of views and sp's :)

Comment: Actually, if the column has to be converted *implicitly*, the (meaningful) use of index is killed as well.

Comment: @AndriyM  If it was numeric type when would <> 0 required an implicit conversion?

Comment: If it was a numeric type, there would be no implicit conversion all right, but why would you assume that `tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY` was numeric?

Comment: Are you referring to this statement: *‘It has to be a numeric type for convert to decimal to succeed’* ? What did you mean by it? For, if taken as is, it is [clearly false](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17991).

Comment: @AndriyM For the second time did you read the answer? "That convert will fail if any varchar value is not decimal."

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that, my fault, I'm sorry. Your former statement about conversion still doesn't sound right, though. I *guess* the implication is "...for successful convert to decimal to be *guaranteed*", but I can assure you, if that is indeed what is implied, it is hardly obvious from your wording.

Answer (score 1):

I made some minor updates and formatting to the query that may be helpful; checking for `IS NULL` and empty string by using `COALESCE` instead of with `CASE` statements. See below for details. I'm not sure if these will affect performance, but you can try it.

Please note that your last criteria was listed the twice. I'm not sure if that was intentional or not or if it will even make a difference in performance. Let me know. If not, then I will delete this answer.

```
SELECT
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ID,
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_LBR_HRS,
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.CUSTNAME,
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.JOBNBR,
    --CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10,   5), dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY) END AS COMPQTY,
    COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY), 0) AS COMPQTY
    --CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10,    5), dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END AS ORDQTY,
    COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY), 0) AS ORDQTY
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.PLAN_CD,
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.PLANQTY,
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ITEMNBR,
    dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF.ITEM_NBR,
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WODUEDT,
    tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.WRK_CENTER_DESC,
    tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.LABOR_CAPACITY,
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_SETUP_HRS,
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.STD_LBR_HOURS,
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE,
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR,
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS,
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPERATION_NBR,
    tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.WAREHOUSE,
    CASE
        WHEN
            dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20005'
        THEN
            1
        WHEN
            dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20010'
        THEN
            2
        WHEN
            dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR  = '20020'
        THEN
            3
        WHEN
            dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20030'
        THEN
            4
        WHEN
            dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20040'
        THEN
            5
        WHEN
            dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20050'
        THEN
            6
        WHEN
            dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR = '20110'
        THEN
            7
        ELSE
            dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR
        END
            AS WCOrder,
    DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(dw, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE), dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE) AS WeekEnd,
    DATEPART(wk, dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE) AS WkNum,
    CASE
        WHEN
            dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY <> 0
        THEN
            ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_LBR_HRS / dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) * (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY - dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY)) * 2
        ELSE
            ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_LBR_HRS / dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) * (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY)) * 2
        END AS RmnLabor,
    CASE
        WHEN
            dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY <> 0
        THEN
            ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_SETUP_HRS / tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) * (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY - dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY)) / 100
        ELSE
            ((dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.STD_SETUP_HRS / dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) * (dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY)) / 100
        END AS RmnSetup
FROM
    dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF
        ON
            dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF.CPN = dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.CPN_NO INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF AS tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF
                ON
                    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WC_NBR = tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.ID INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF
                        ON
                            dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ID = dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.ID
WHERE
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.SCHED_COMP_DATE <= DATEADD(m, 2, GETDATE())
        AND
    (
        dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS <> 'C'
            OR
        --dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS IS NULL OR dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS = ''
        --Replace the above statement with the following...
        COALESCE(dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.OPER_STATUS, N'') = N''
    )
        AND
    tbl_WORK_CENTR_NF.WAREHOUSE = '02'
        AND
    dbo.tbl_WIPOPER_NF.WORK_CENTER_NBR IN ('20005', '20010', '20020', '20030', '20040', '20060','20110')
        AND
    dbo.tbl_ITEMMAST_NF.ITEM_NBR NOT LIKE 'A%'
        AND
    --CASE WHEN tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END <> 0
    --I would change the above statement to this...
    COALESCE(tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY, 0) <> 0

        --AND
    --CASE WHEN tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY) END <> 0
    --The above statement is a duplicate!
ORDER BY
    dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.WODUEDT DESC
```

Comment: See comment that tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY is varchar.  where '0.0' <> '0' returns true

Comment: If I do this
COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.COMPQTY), 0) AS COMPQTY,
COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(10, 5), dbo.tbl_SFCWRK_SQL_NF.ORDQTY), 0) AS ORDQTY

then shouldnt I use those alias column names in calcs?

Comment: @Ryan, are you talking about in the where clause? If so, then you can not use aliased columns in a where clause unless you use a sub-query. Will that increase performance? Possibly, something to probably look into.